# Error after deploying R shiny app (object not found)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on my first `shiny` app and I am running into an issue while publishing the app to the shinyapp.io server. The app runs fine in my R Studio locally, however after deploying and when opened in a web browser, it shows an error message in the logs: `“Warning: Error in unique: object 'df_app_MT' not found”.` But 'df_app_MT' already exists in the .Rdata. I have gone through several posts, but error persists.

I have placed (ui.R, server.R and the .Rdata) within the app's folder. Also checked the shinydashboard, the application (status shows “running”). Here is my current ui.R code and log details along with a screenshot. Please assist me how to fix this issue.

Thank you,
Toufiq

**ui.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr) 
library(ComplexHeatmap) 
library(ggplot2)
library(BiocManager)
options(repos = BiocManager::repositories())


load("datafile.RData")

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Testing") ,
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("MENU")
                      ),
                      sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
                      
                      
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem("gridfingerprint",
                                fluidRow(
                                  
                                  box(width = NULL,solidHeader = TRUE,
                                      plotOutput("plot2", height = 500)
                                      
                                  ),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    
                                    box(width = NULL,solidHeader = TRUE,
                                        plotOutput("plot_map", height = 500))
                                  ),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(width = 4,
                                           box(width = NULL,status = "warning",
                                               downloadButton("gridplot",label = "Download image")
                                           )
                                    ),
                                    column(width = 3, offset = 1,
                                           box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                                               downloadButton("downloadlist",label = "Download table")    
                                           ))
                                    
                                  )
                                )
                        ),
                        tabItem(tabName = "individualfingerprint", 
                                h5("Fingerprint heatmap displaying patterns of annotated modules across individual study subjects"),
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(width = 12,solidHeader = TRUE, (div(style='width:1400px;overflow: auto;height:800px;',
                                                                          plotOutput("plot4",height = 1200, width = 2550)))
                                  ),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(width = 4,
                                           box(width = NULL,status = "warning",
                                               downloadButton("downloadindplot",label = "Download image")
                                           )
                                    ),
                                    column(width = 3, offset = 1,
                                           box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                                               downloadButton("individualtable",label = "Download table")    
                                           ))
                                    
                                  )
                                )),
                        
                        tabItem("complexplot",
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(width = 12,
                                         box(width = NULL,solidHeader = TRUE, (div(style='width:1400px;overflow: auto;',
                                                                                   plotOutput("plot3",height = 800, width = 4600)))),
                                         fluidRow(
                                           column(width = 4,
                                                  box(width = NULL,status = "warning",
                                                      downloadButton("aggregateplot",label = "Download image")
                                                  )
                                           ),
                                           column(width = 3, offset = 1,
                                                  box(width = NULL, status = "warning",
                                                      downloadButton("downloadaggregate",label = "Download table")    
                                                  ))
                                           
                                         )
                                  )
                                  
                                ))
                      )
                    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
server = function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("FINGERPRINT GRIDS", tabName = "gridfingerprint"),
      menuItem("Choose disease", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               # Input directly under menuItem
               selectInput(inputId = "diseaseInput",
                           label = "",
                           choices = unique(df_app_MT$diseases), multiple=F, selectize=TRUE,
                           width = '98%'), tabName = "gridfingerprint"),
      
      
      menuItem("MODULES X STUDIES", tabName = "complexplot"),
      menuItem("Choose aggregate", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               # Input directly under menuItem
               selectInput(inputId = "aggregateInput",
                           label = "",
                           choices = unique(df_app_MT$Aggregate), multiple=F, selectize=TRUE,
                           width = '98%'),tabName = "complexplot"),
      

      menuItem("MODULES X INDIVIDUALS", tabName = "individualfingerprint"),
      menuItem("Choose disease", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               # Input directly under menuItem
               selectInput(inputId = "IllnessInput",
                           label = "",
                           choices = unique(Ind_table_MT$Illness), multiple=F, selectize=TRUE,
                           width = '80%'),
               menuItem("Choose aggregate"),
               selectInput(inputId = "IndaggregateInput",
                           label = "",
                           choices = unique(df_app_MT$Aggregate),selected ="A1", multiple=T, selectize=TRUE,
                           width = '80%'),tabName = "individualfingerprint")
      


    }
  )
}
```

**logs details**

```
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853366+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Bioconductor page: http://bioconductor.org/packages/ComplexHeatmap/
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853367+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Github page: https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853367+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Documentation: http://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853368+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Gu, Z. Complex heatmaps reveal patterns and correlations in multidimensional 
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853369+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:   genomic data. Bioinformatics 2016.
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853369+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: This message can be suppressed by:
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853369+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:   suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ComplexHeatmap))
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853370+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: ========================================
2021-04-29T02:08:20.853370+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: 
2021-04-29T02:08:21.178976+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), ?BiocManager::install for help
2021-04-29T02:08:24.452402+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Warning: Error in unique: object 'df_app_MT' not found
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459069+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:   114: unique
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459069+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:   108: renderUI [/srv/connect/apps/test/server.R#3]
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459071+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:    94: renderFunc
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459084+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:     7: connect$retry
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459070+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:   107: func
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459071+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:    93: output$menu
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459071+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:    13: runApp
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459083+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:    12: fn
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459085+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:     5: eval
2021-04-29T02:08:24.459084+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]:     6: eval
2021-04-29T02:42:03.040084+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Running on host: ebb9348b6b95
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046218+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046231+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046234+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: R version: 4.0.3
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046237+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: shiny version: 1.6.0
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046237+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: httpuv version: 1.5.5
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046247+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046281+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: knitr version: (none)
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046298+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046308+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046478+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-04-29T02:42:03.046308+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: htmltools version: 0.5.1
2021-04-29T02:42:03.256647+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Starting R with process ID: '24'
2021-04-29T02:42:03.253079+00:00 shinyapps[4042863]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
```

Comment: Could you also share `server` code?

Comment: @Waldi, thank you very much. I have included the server.R code in the question (see above).

Comment: Does the app work in local if you restart R session?

Comment: @Waldi, the issue is now resolved. I created an app.R file (combined ui.R and server.R) > loaded the .Rdata. Ran the app. The issue is now resolved. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, perfect, good you found out!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how switching from a split app to a single-file app would change anything, but the app may have been unable to locate the .RData file in the same working directory first time around. Locally, this may have been ignored if df_app_MT happened to be in your working environment.

Comment: I tried many ways and followed suggestions when I had ui.R and server.R. it did not work even though .RData was available. So lastly, I made app.R and ran shinyApp (ui =ui,  server= server) using the same I was able to deploy.